# Invalid Container 'DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE' in manifest

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace, manifest.json

I am getting the following error message when trying to publish an app to G Suite Marketplace from [Chrome developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard). I am following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing).

[image]

Below is my manifest.json file.

```
{
  "name": "Test Publishing",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "api_console_project_id": "poj_id",
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "https://example.com/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "https://example.com"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "example_icon_128.png"
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Is this now changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may know, G Suite extensions are being [migrated](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrating-gsuite-extensions-from-chrome-web-store-to-gsuite-marketplace) from the Chrome Web Store to the G Suite Marketplace.

Web apps can now be published to the G Suite Marketplace directly from the Cloud Console without having to publish them in the Chrome Web Store. See the note at the top of https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm.